# how to add instances in a list?

Tags: clips

I'm working with CLIPS and I'm getting in trouble when trying to add instances in an empty list. I'm using the insert$ function but does not seem to work properly. The concrete code is this:

```
(loop-for-count (?i 1 (length$ ?listaConvocatoriasAlumno))
            (if (neq (nth$ ?i ?listaConvocatoriasAlumno) ?convocatoria)
                then
                    (if (eq (str-compare (send (instance-address * (nth$ ?i ?listaConvocatoriasAlumno)) get-cuadrimestre) ?cuadrimestre) 0)
                        then
                            (insert$ ?listaConvocatoriasMismoCuadrimestre (+ (length$ ?listaConvocatoriasMismoCuadrimestre) 1) (nth$ ?i ?listaConvocatoriasAlumno))
                    )
            )
        )
```

?listaConvocatoriasAlumno contains multiples instances of a certain class and I would like to add some of these into another list (?listaConvocatoriasMismoCuadrimestre in this case) which at the beginning of the loop is empty.

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just forgot to store the insert return value into the list variable... I'm getting old